# Revit api import size lookup table to "Pipe Accessory" or "Plumbing Fixture"

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to import loookuptabledata.csv to different families using :

```C
Document DstnctFamEdt = actvDoc.EditFamily(DstnctFam);
FamilySizeTableManager fstm = FamilySizeTableManager.GetFamilySizeTableManager(DstnctFamEdt,DstnctFamEdt.OwnerFamily.Id);
```

I am able to successfully do that to "Pipe Fitting" families.  However when i apply the same code to a "Pipe Accessory" family or a "Plumbing Fixture" Family, i get this error:

```html
lookupTableResult Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference is not set to an instance object.
```

I have tried to import a lookuptable csv file "manually" into these types of families, and Revit (2022) does not complain about it.

Any pointers on how to import loookuptable csv file into "Pipe Accessory" Families and "Plumbing Fixture" Families?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So i Figured it out....

It seems that it has nothing to do with Family Type as in if it is a Fitting, Accessory  or a fixture.
What it has to do with, is whether the family have a lookuptable manager to begin with.  if you happened to have csv files in your family already, the above code will work fine.
However, if you do not have any csv in your family, then you have to CREATE and new lookuptable manager, then get it.

So i modified my code the following, and it now works for all families:

```c
Document DstnctFamEdt = actvDoc.EditFamily(DstnctFam);
// Get FamilySizeTableManager  (FSTM)
FamilySizeTableManager fstm = FamilySizeTableManager.GetFamilySizeTableManager(DstnctFamEdt, 
DstnctFamEdt.OwnerFamily.Id);

// if FSTM is NUll then it does not exist=> Create one
if (fstm == null) {
   bool fstmResult = FamilySizeTableManager.CreateFamilySizeTableManager(DstnctFamEdt, DstnctFamEdt.OwnerFamily.Id);
// Check that you actually created and FSTM, and Retrieve it.
if (fstmResult) {
fstm = FamilySizeTableManager.GetFamilySizeTableManager(DstnctFamEdt,  DstnctFamEdt.OwnerFamily.Id);
  }
}

// If FSTM Does Exit then Load csv File and Save Family and load into original DOC that family exists in.
if (fstm != null) {

// Import the csv file into Family... transaction needed
Transaction importTrans = new Transaction(DstnctFam.Document, "Importing csv File into Family ");

importTrans.Start("Start"); 
FamilySizeTableErrorInfo errorInfo = new FamilySizeTableErrorInfo();
FamilySizeTableErrorInfo ImportErrorInfo = new FamilySizeTableErrorInfo();
fstm.ImportSizeTable(DstnctFamEdt, csvFilePath, ImportErrorInfo);
                    
// End transaction
importTrans.Commit();

// Load Family into Doc where it exists after adding csv file.
DstnctFamEdt.LoadFamily(actvDoc, new familyLoadOptions()); //update begins here

SaveAsOptions saveoptions = new SaveAsOptions();
saveoptions.OverwriteExistingFile = true;
// Save the Family if you want to, otherwise, make sure you save the Host doc.
DstnctFamEdt.SaveAs(DstnctFamPath, saveoptions);
// Cloes Family.
DstnctFamEdt.Close(false);
```

Ok, let me know if anyone can add to this.

thanks